# InApp Purchases Single AppleId

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How can i Handle this issue when user purchase my product first time on the device and then it login to same id on other device and restore the product . this will be the loop hole ,how can i tackle this problem , is it handle by apple or manually handle this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchases are linked to an Apple ID, not a device.  Once a user purchases a non-consumable item they are entitled to use that purchase on any device that is linked with their Apple ID.

Comment: Can i make packges such that for 1 month subscription or 1 week subscription in in app purchases??

Comment: You can use subscription in-app purchases if that is appropriate for your content, but again the user can activate this on any number of devices  associated with their Apple ID